# How do I create new directory asp.net in c++ for window form button click

Tags: asp.net, c++

I would like to know how to create folder in c++ for asp.net

```
System::IO::IsolatedStorage::IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile::GetStore( static_cast<IsolatedStorageScope>(IsolatedStorageScope::User);
```

isoFile->CreateDirectory()

I have created windows form in c++ with a button. When I click on the button it should take a path as input and create a folder.

eg.

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     }
```

This is not working. I do not want to use `<boost/filesystem.hpp>`. Please let me know how I could do this.

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net or WinForms? Where do you want to create the folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx), like this:

```
System::IO::Directory::CreateDirectory(path);
```